# Storing query string parameters in session cookie

Tags: javascript, session, cookies

I have the need to store users initial query string parameters during their stay on a webpage. I decided to parse the query string parameters and stick them in a session cookie so when I have code that needs the initial query parameters I call the cookie.

This seems to not always work, esp in IE.  Can anyone give me some suggestions? I thought maybe to store it in the dom storage but I'm not sure if that is the right approach. 
The code lives in my page header and is accessible on all the pages of the site.

Here is what I put together:

```
var urlParams;
(window.onpopstate = function () {
   var match,
       pl     = /\+/g,
       search = /([^&=]+)=?([^&]*)/g,
       decode = function (s) { return decodeURIComponent(s.replace(pl, " ")); },
       query  = window.location.search.substring(1);

   urlParams = {};
   while (match = search.exec(query))
      urlParams[decode(match[1])] = decode(match[2]);
})();

function set_cookie(name, value) {
  var cookie = [name, '=', JSON.stringify(value), '; domain=.', window.location.host.toString(), '; path=/;'].join('');
  document.cookie = cookie;
}

function read_cookie(name) {
 var result = document.cookie.match(new RegExp(name + '=([^;]+)'));
 result && (result = JSON.parse(result[1]));
 return result;
}

if(read_cookie('tbts') === null){
  set_cookie('tbts', urlParams);
}

var urlParamsCookie = read_cookie('tbts');
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify which version of IE, but according to [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/history), `popstate` isn't available until IE10.

Comment: I was testing in IE10.  The urlParamsCookie var doesn't always show up in the dom.  Can you suggest an alternative to window.onpopstate?  Also, thank you for that site I didn't know about it.